# Bitcoin Cash - How to get estimated fee and send transaction

Tags: bitcoin-cash, exchange-fees

Last week I started working with Bitcoins and needed to show the transaction fee. While working with Bitcoins, I used:

- https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/api/v1/fees/recommended
- https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main

Now I need to do it with Bitcoin Cash (BCH). I was reading something about it and it is a fork of Bitcoin. Are they using same fees?

I have been searching and found many sites showing average fee, is that the standard on BCH?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The fees for Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash are not fixed, but are driven by supply (block space) and demand (transaction volume) in their respective markets.  They are independent of each other, so prevailing fees for Bitcoin are not likely to be representative of Bitcoin Cash fees.

I don't know of any sites that track Bitcoin Cash fees in the same way as Bitcoin.  However you can see some historical data at sites like [this one](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin%20cash-median_transaction_fee.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Question, do you know if they are transfer fees per KB or per Byte? I used BTC to evaluate and for that coin it is KB, I guess is the same for BCH.

Comment: @Eduardo: Same difference.  Whatever the fee is per byte, multiply by 1000 to get the fee per KB, or divide to go the other way.

Comment: sorry I did not explain correctly, I meant if in the page you suggest (bitinfocharts), the transfer fees they are showing are in USD per Byte or per KB.

Comment: Oh I see.  I think it is the median fee for the entire transaction, over all transactions of all sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the estimatefee RPC call? This will calculate the amount needed per kilobyte.

For example calling bitcoin-cli estimatefee 2 would provide a fee per kb to try to get confirmed within 2 blocks.

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#estimatefee

This command works for Bitcoin Cash too, now what you have to do after that is get the USD price of Bitcoin Cash from an API.

Answer (score 0):

come here :

https://bch.btc.com/stats/unconfirmed-tx

you can see the  Current best transaction fees1 Satoshis/byte | 0.00001 BCH/KB